# Andengine Rotate Wheel with fast acceleration

Tags: android, rotation, andengine

I have a Wheel sprite and i am rotating it using Physics RevoluteJointDef. Its rotating.
But problem is how i can make wheel to start moving fast. It took the speed after sometime like real.

```
// Create body for green rectangle (Static)
    final Body greenBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(pw, greenRectangle, BodyType.StaticBody, PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0));

    // Create body for red rectangle (Dynamic, for our arm)
    final Body redBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(pw, wheel, BodyType.DynamicBody, PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.1f));
    pw.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(wheel, redBody, true, true));

    // Create revolute joint, connecting those two bodies 
    final RevoluteJointDef revoluteJointDef = new RevoluteJointDef();
    revoluteJointDef.initialize(greenBody, redBody, greenBody.getWorldCenter());
    revoluteJointDef.localAnchorA.set(0,0);
    revoluteJointDef.localAnchorB.set(0,0);

    revoluteJointDef.enableMotor = true;
    revoluteJointDef.motorSpeed = 100;
    revoluteJointDef.maxMotorTorque = 1000;



    pw.createJoint(revoluteJointDef);

    registerUpdateHandler(pw);
```

Comment: http://www.matim-dev.com/revolute-joint.html
you can solve this with that link

Comment: "It took the speed after sometime like real" - this is incomprehensible, sorry.  Can you explain more clearly what you have working now and what you're trying to do?

Comment: i am working on game and want to rotate Wheel of furtune in it.